Is mint account keypair stored when creating it via CLI
Is the randomly generated keypair stored somewhere when creating a new mint account using the sp-token CLI?
 spl-token create-token 


Using the CLI does not store the keypair.
If you did want a keypair you should do it manually as follows;
solana-keygen new -o token.json
And then use it
spl-token create-token token.json
This will allow you to grind a vanity address and then use it as well as have access to the keypair as per requirements.
